# Update field based on another field in the document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to update a document field based on another field using the update operator?

[See playground here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xQ64DPO3lgS)

I have players collection with health and maxHealth, my goal is to reset the player health to the maxHealth value

```
db={
  "players": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5fba17c1c4566e57fafdcd7e"),
      "username": "moshe",
      "health": 0,
      "maxHealth": 200,
      
    }
  ]
}

// update
db.players.update({
  username: "moshe"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "health": "$$maxHealth",
    
  }
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: use $maxHealth instead of $$maxHealth

Comment: I've tried that, it's not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting **from MongoDB v4.2**,

```
PlayersSchema.update(
  { username: "moshe" },
  [{
    "$set": { "health": "$maxHealth" }
  }]
)
```

---

**Below MongoDB v4.2**

1. using `find()` and `save()`

```
PlayersSchema.find({ username: "moshe" }).forEach(function(doc){
  doc.health = doc.maxHealth; 
  doc.save();
})
```

2. using `find()` and [bulkWrite()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite)

```
const players = await PlayersSchema.find({ username: "moshe" }, { maxHealth: 1 });
const updatePlayers = players.map(({ _id, maxHealth }) => ({
  updateOne: {
    filter: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) },
    update: { health: maxHealth }
  }
}));
PlayersSchema.bulkWrite(updatePlayers).then(res => {
   console.log(res.insertedCount, res.modifiedCount, res.deletedCount);
});
```

Comment: There is an option to do that only with the update/updateMany query?
I tried your first methods but I'm getting errors
[![image.png](https://i.postimg.cc/s2xNb2Wv/image.png)](https://postimg.cc/SX0dMkDh)

Comment: it will support in any update function, Mongo playground in not supporting this syntax you should try in your mongo shell or your nodejs code.